# Magento tracking code for affiliate programs

Tags: ecommerce-tracking, affiliate

I registered for ShareASale affiliate marketing program and was asked to put a tracking code on my site. Does anyone know where that taking code goes? I have Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 if that helps. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere on google or youtube.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Custom code

   You will be marking changes to the following file:
   /app/design/frontend/default/[templatename]/template/checkout/success.phtml

   (if this file does not exist, please modify this file instead: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml )

   Find the line that reads:

   ```
   <p><strong><?php echo $this->__('Thank you for your purchase!') ?></strong></p>
   ```

   and just below that line, add the following code:

   ```
   <?php
   $_customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
   $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
   $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
   $order->load($lastOrderId);
   $_totalData =$order->getData();
   $_sub = $_totalData['subtotal'];
   ?>
   <img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?tracking=<?php echo $this->getOrderId() ?>&amount=<?php echo $_sub ?>&transtype=sale&merchantID=XXXX" width="1" height="1">
   ```

   Where you replace XXXX with your merchant ID number.
2. Extension

   See this link:
   https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shareasale-tracking-pixel.html
   ( As it says by developer, It can be community version too)

> Does anyone know where that tracking code goes?
>   It will track all the clicks and sales from Shareasale affiliates.